# Macros with return value

Tags: objective-c, swift, macros

I'm trying to reproduce this pattern in Swift

```
#define mustBeKindOfClassFailedReturn(object, objectClass, ret) \
if(![object isKindOfClass:objectClass]) { \
NSLog(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ must be kind of %@ class, current class is %@", object, NSStringFromClass(objectClass), NSStringFromClass([object class])])) \
return ret; }
```

used like this

```
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
    insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

mustNotBeNilFailedReturn(self.adapter, UIEdgeInsetsZero)
mustBeKindOfClassFailedReturn(self.adapter, [WBCollectionViewSectionAdapter class], UIEdgeInsetsZero)
```

Does anyone know a good solution to this?

**Edit**

I know about guard but using guard i have to rewrite a lot of code each time i'll have to override a method in my subclasses for exemple

```
/**
* mustOverride
*/
#define mustOverride \
{ NSLog(@"You must override this function") }

#define mustOverrideFailedReturn(ret) \
{ mustOverride \
return ret; }
```

**EDIT 2**

I've ended with solution is it the optimal one ?

```
func needOverride(function: String = __FUNCTION__, file: String = __FILE__, line: Int = __LINE__) -> Bool {

    REVLogManager.SharedInstance.logErrorMessage("You must override this function", function: function, file: file, line: line, exception: nil, error: nil)

    return false

}

func doesObject(function: String = __FUNCTION__, file: String = __FILE__, line: Int = __LINE__, matchingObject: AnyObject!, matchesClass matchingClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {

    guard matchingObject.isKindOfClass(matchingClass) else {

        let message = "\(matchingObject) must be kind of \(matchingClass) class, current class is \(matchingObject.dynamicType)"
        REVLogManager.SharedInstance.logErrorMessage(message, function: function, file: file, line: line, exception: nil, error: nil)

        return false

    }

    return true

}
```

I'm calling the method like this

```
public func actualScrollOffsetDistanceWithScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView!) -> Float {

    guard needOverride() else { return 0.0 }
    return 0.0

}
```

And

```
guard doesObject(matchingObject: self, matchesClass: REVListSectionAdapter.classForCoder()) else { return }
```

Comment: What is "ret" Supposed to be?

Comment: It could be anything : Float, Int, AnyObject, Bool, UIEdgeInsets and even nil

Answer (score 0):

My answer follows the same legacy pattern using in Swift.  You can use `classForCoder`, but I prefer `dynamicType` for type checking.

```
func mustBeKindOfClassFailedReturn(object: AnyObject, objectClass: AnyClass, returnVal: Any?) {
    if !object.isKindOfClass(objectClass) {
        print("\(object) must be kind of \(objectClass) class, current class is \(object.dynamicType)")
        return returnVal
    }
    return nil // or UIEdgeInsetsZero, or whatever
}
```

You may also get similar results with `!(object is objectClass)`, but things get tricky when comparing certain number types.  See [Swift type inference and type checking issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35047451/2415822)

You can also replace `AnyObject` and `Any` with `NSObject` if you know you're dealing with Objective-C types.  From your comment it seems like `ret` could be a value type, so that's why I make it an `Any` type.

Comment: But like this even if my object is the correct class i'll return "returnVal" which is not ok to me

Comment: @Pwyll28 ah I misread your macro, edited my answer to return nil if the class doesn't match.

Comment: Is this doing anything other than re-writing "if let" or "guard let" ?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ it keeps the logging and the legacy style.  If the OP wants more Swift-y code, they can go with an `if let` or `guard`.

Comment: I suppose if you're going to write Objective-C in Swift that's fine, but good swift code (IMO) should be written to either handle those kind of cases implicitly or, ideally, written so they won't happen at all. (yay!) :-)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I think that's up to the OP to decide which way they want to write their code.

Comment: Your solution does not suit me, in my old macros, when the condition is correct my macro simply "does nothing"

Comment: @Pwyll28 you're going to have to refactor your code a little bit.  Your macro takes care of the return for you in Objective-C.  In Swift, there's really no way to do that.  You can import this macro through a bridging header if you really need the exact functionality.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ can you check my new edit and tell if it is the correct implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

Swift has a better solution for this kind of problem, [the guard statement](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-guard-better-than-if/). In this case, just put this in your method.

```
guard let adapter = self.adapter as? WBCollectionViewSectionAdapter else {
/* return value if the adapter is not setup properly. */
    return .Zero
}
/* continue with valid and correctly classed adapter */
```

If you're looking for a way to handle this for sub classes, you may want to consider [generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html). It will allow you implicit type safety without having to rewrite logic in your subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't have a macro capability of this kind.

In terms of accomplishing your goal. The pattern you are following would most correctly be handled using `guard` statements.  A function containing a guard statement must exit the enclosing scope (or trap) and may do so with a return.

Please check the Swift documentation for information about Control Flow and Early Exit control